# How to debug stuck Akka stream?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am trying to debug an akka stream which in one situation, is pulling new data OK, but in another situation, is getting "stuck" and not pulling new data. This is all fully reproducible, but the second situation is quite complicated and requires several minutes of setup to get going. The thing is, this Akka stream is actually created mostly by akka-http and akka-actor code, so I don't actually know what it looks like under the hood, and it's not obvious from reading the code that I've read so far.

So what I would like to do is:

- See what the overall materialised stream graph looks like, or at least see all the construction in one place, rather than scattered over various source files. Is there a way to log out the materialised graph?
- See what is causing the relevant pull to happen in the first situation. The thing is, there are other pulls happening which may or may not be relevant, so just putting a breakpoint on a pull-related method might lead to confusing, irrelevant hits.
- Figure out why that same pull is not happening in the second situation.

I already have a rough idea of what the problem *probably* is - my code is not asynchronous enough - but I need to understand what is going on precisely, so that I can write a regression test that reproduces the problem quickly, without the need for all this complicated setup that I have in the second situation.

I have enabled the following debug options and enabled DEBUG level logging for everything, but it's still not logging enough information, as far as I can see.

```
akka {
  http {
    host-connection-pool {
      idle-timeout = infinite
    }
  }
  io {
    tcp {
      trace-logging = on
      windows-connection-abort-workaround-enabled = auto
    }
  }
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

Comment: Without a code snippet, it would be difficult to help with your exact issue. Can you try producing one with https://scastie.scala-lang.org?

Comment: Too much synchronous code will generally manifest itself in thread starvation in the various dispatchers/`ExecutionContext`s.  If you're a lightbend subscriber, it's well worth using the thread starvation detector to track down this sort of thing; if you're not it's not too difficult to implement something which runs in its own threadpool and schedules short tasks in the dispatchers/ECs, logging errors if it can't do so fast enough.